# how to enable JavaScript debugging in visual studio 2019 behind .cshtml page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

My Visual studio 2019 +, My code is asp.net mvc project,
When I pointing on .chtml page behind java script debugging point, its cant working step by step, But when its pointing separate  JavaScript file then its working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIOve.png)

Answer (score 0):

Open Project ->Ensure your ASP.NET project is open in Visual Studio 2019.then Set Breakpoints ->Add breakpoints in your .cshtml file where you want to debug JavaScript or Razor code and then Run & Attach -> Run the project (F5).Open .cshtml in a browser.
In Visual Studio, go to Debug > Attach to Process.
Choose your web app's process (e.g., w3wp.exe or dotnet.exe).
Select "Script" Code:
In the "Attach to Process" dialog, choose the "Script" code type for JavaScript debugging.

Click Attach ->
Click "Attach" to connect Visual Studio to the running process.

Trigger Breakpoints ->
Go back to the browser, perform actions triggering JavaScript, and Visual Studio will hit your breakpoints.

Note -> Ensure your browser allows debugging, and consider using a compatible browser like Google Chrome with the Visual Studio Code extension. Steps might vary based on your project and tools used.